# Python Parser for text file to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, parsing, pandas

is there any python library to parse the information below as data frame in pandas?

```
product/productId: B0000630MQ
review/userId: unknown
review/profileName: unknown
review/helpfulness: 2/2
review/score: 5.0
review/time: 1058745600
review/summary: Super product!  I'm very happy.
review/text: The batteries are excellent (1850's), and the charger is super fast, and stops charging when done.  I love that you just plug the unit right into the wall with no unruly cords.  My Sony digital only takes 2 AA batteries, so with this charger, I always have two sets of spare batteries with me in my case.  This charger even charges up my SONY AA batteries that came with the camera. Highly recommended!
```

Thanks for your attention.

Best Regards,
Santiago

Comment: [This similar (not duplicate) question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15907869/reading-key-value-pairs-into-pandas) prompted a discussion of several approaches that could work for you as well. Try them out, and if you can't make them work, show us an example of what you've tried.

Comment: Thanks for the link. It's different Allan. Because that example is using CSV file format while the question is about different format as mentioned in the question.

Comment: I'm referring to the key/value nature of your question. Where you have ``:``, the question addresses ``=``, but of course it's the same problem. Your data could be read in as a "CSV" file with one item per line (so, no commas). Assuming you have multiple entries like this and you want to put them into a table format, you should look at ``stack`` and ``unstack`` in the documentation.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23331480/converting-amazon-data-into-csv-format-in-python