# Load data and average in single operation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to load data of the form shown below into a dataframe.

```
popSize: 1000
numSurvivors: 0
tournamentSize: 10
probMutation: 0.1
probCrossover: 0.9
numIters: 100
Accuracy: 96.84 
Error Rate: 3.16 
Not Classified: 0.00
Total time: 5.367

popSize: 1000
numSurvivors: 0
tournamentSize: 10
probMutation: 0.1
probCrossover: 0.9
numIters: 100
Accuracy: 96.84 
Error Rate: 3.16 
Not Classified: 0.00
Total time: 4.472

popSize: 1000
numSurvivors: 0
tournamentSize: 10
probMutation: 0.1
probCrossover: 0.9
numIters: 100
Accuracy: 92.11 
Error Rate: 7.89 
Not Classified: 0.00
Total time: 4.46
```

The data represents multiple executions of an algorithm.
Is there a way to load this data as a single row, using an averaged result for the final 4 values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a method for wrangling your data into a dataframe using `itertools.groupby()` and `pandas`:

```
from itertools import groupby
import pandas as pd

with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:

    chunks = [list(group) for k, group in groupby(f.readlines(), lambda x: x=='\n') if not k]

chunks = [dict([tuple(i.strip().split(': ')) for i in chunk]) for chunk in chunks]

df = pd.DataFrame(chunks).astype(float)
```

Returns:

```
  Accuracy Error Rate Not Classified Total time numIters numSurvivors popSize  \
0    96.84       3.16           0.00      5.367      100            0    1000   
1    96.84       3.16           0.00      4.472      100            0    1000   
2    92.11       7.89           0.00       4.46      100            0    1000   

  probCrossover probMutation tournamentSize  
0           0.9          0.1             10  
1           0.9          0.1             10  
2           0.9          0.1             10
```

You can then easily calculate the mean like so:

```
df[['Accuracy','Error Rate','Not Classified','Total time']].mean()
```

Returns:

```
Accuracy          95.263333
Error Rate         4.736667
Not Classified     0.000000
Total time         4.766333
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thanks! Are you aware of any way that I could average these values into a single row?

Comment: Something like `pd.DataFrame(df[['Accuracy','Error Rate','Not Classified','Total time']].mean()).transpose()` for  a data frame with 1 row.

Answer (score 0):

```
# Test data 
text = """popSize: 1000
numSurvivors: 0
tournamentSize: 10
probMutation: 0.1
probCrossover: 0.9
numIters: 100
Accuracy: 96.84 
Error Rate: 3.16 
Not Classified: 0.00
Total time: 5.36

popSize: 1000
numSurvivors: 0
tournamentSize: 10
probMutation: 0.1
probCrossover: 0.9
numIters: 100
Accuracy: 96.84 
Error Rate: 3.16 
Not Classified: 0.00
Total time: 4.472

popSize: 1000
numSurvivors: 0
tournamentSize: 10
probMutation: 0.1
probCrossover: 0.9
numIters: 100
Accuracy: 92.11 
Error Rate: 7.89 
Not Classified: 0.00
Total time: 4.46
"""

import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

import pandas as pd

# Function invoked by pandas read on each element, for conversion. Here
# just return the right hand side of the value delimited by ":"
def value(item):
    return item[item.find(':')+1:]

# Reformat the incoming text to comma delimited, each double line break is a record break.
text2 = text.replace(": ", ":").replace("\n\n", "$$break$$").replace("\n", ",").replace("$$break$$","\n").replace("\n,", "")


## Adapted from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15907869/reading-key-value-pairs-into-pandas
## read table applying a coverter fucntion per element, and supplying the column names
df = pd.read_table(StringIO(text2), header=None, delimiter=',',
                   converters={i:value for i in range(11)},
                   names=['popSize','numSurvivors','tournamentSize','probMutation','probCrossover','numIters','Accuracy','Error Rate','Not Classified','Total time'])
```